# Al publicar mi proyecto asp.net no genera el compilado de una Referencia de Servicio

Tags: asp.net, webservice, aplicación-web, deployment, publish

tengo un problema, hace poco me incluyeron en un proyecto, al realizar algunos cambios e intentar publicarlos, me doy con la sorpresa que al momento de generar el publicado no genera la carpeta de la referencia de servicio sobre la cual hice los cambios(wsRPI).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como puedo resolver ese problema?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Necesito que al publicar, genere todas las referencias de servicio, especififamente la del servicio wsRPI.